# Cleaning this data with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm trying to drill down a column of data in an excel file that I'm importing as a panda into Python to more manageable items.

[image: This is a picture of some of the data I'm trying to clean]

As you can see, there's a lot of different ways to say Lymphoma. I'm trying to get these items down to just the base condition, so for any kind of Lymphoma, just Lymphoma. For Cancer, just cancer, as so on.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: If you are not concerned with typos and the likes, you could just check for membership and re-label them, e.g. `df.Conditions[df.Conditions.str.contains('Lymphoma')] = 'Lymphoma'`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to replace the entire string with the keyword:

```
df['Conditions'].str.replace('.*(Lymphoma|Cancer).*', '\\1', case=False)
```

But this solution is rather imprecise. It doesn't work if there are certain types of lymphoma that should be actually be considered cancer, or lymphoma conditions that do not contain the keyword "lymphoma".

---

A more precise approach is to explicitly list all conditions that are considered lymphoma and cancer and replace them accordingly:

```
replacements = {
    'Lymphoma': ['Lymphoma', 'Follicular Lymphoma', 'Lymphoma, B-Cell', 'B-Cell Lymphoma', 'XYZ'],
    'Cancer': ['Cancer A', 'Cancer B']
}

# explode requires pandas 0.25 or later
s = pd.Series(replacements).explode()
m = pd.Series(s.index, index=s.str.upper()).to_dict()

df['Conditions'].str.upper().map(m)
```

The `upper` calls are there to deal with character case.